# Planet Orbital Zone and Year Length

Tags: planets, orbital-mechanics, stars, habitability, sun

So I'm building a fantasy world that takes place on a planet with a circumference of about 18,500 miles (it's average temperature is 40℉), and it orbits a Blue-Giant.

How long would a year be, and how far away would it orbit its star? (Preferably this is in AU, though any measurement type is fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 100 AU, but life on your planet will probably be roasted

A Blue Giant will produce about 10,000 times the sun's energy. Energy declines  proportional to the square root of distance, so the distance of your planet will be about 100 times the distance to our sun, that is 100AU, to receive the same energy *on average*. If it would have the same atmosphere as Earth, temperature could be similar.

.. but that's on average: you'll have to take into consideration Blue Giants are very wild, unstable, hot stars. There will be a problem with flares,

> A star may be unsuitable for life for other reasons: it may be prone
> to extreme flares, for example. A blue giant is a star that burns
> bright and dies young, only lasting a few million years. Planets
> around such a star would have only just formed (they may still have
> molten surfaces). Blue giants tend to be unstable, being variable over
> a range of timescales, and ejecting large amounts of matter into
> space.

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20610/do-blue-giants-have-a-habitable-zone

Comment: I changed my planet to a red dwarf, because (according to Wikipedia), " ... the ubiquity and longevity of red dwarfs are factors which could provide ample opportunity for any possibility of habitability to be realized."